# SQL ERROR:root:Line magic function

Tags: mysql, sql

I am taking a class and we are using Jupyter notebooks for SQL. I am getting following error. What problem? How to solve?

The following is what I am typing:

```
%load_ext sql
%sql mysql://studentuser:studentpw@mysqlserver/capstone
%sql USE capstone
```

The output shows "0 rows affected".

Then I type: %sql SHOW tables

This generates "ERROR:root:Line magic function `%sql` not found."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you closed and then reopened the notebook at a later time. That error occurs if you do not execute the first command, to connect to the database, before executing the second, to show tables. Be sure to execute all commands when you open the notebook.